# Команда bash с $(subshell) не работает через Make

Tags: bash, makefile

Задача:

1. Найти работающий контейнер по имени образа. Такой контейнер точно один.
2. Выполнить в этом контейнере команду.

Просто в баше работает:

```
docker exec -it $(docker ps -a | grep name | awk '{print $1}') gulp
```

Через Makefile не работает:

Makefile:

```
task:
    docker exec -it $(docker ps -a | grep name | awk '{print $1}') gulp
```

bash:

```
make task

docker exec -it  gulp
"docker exec" requires at least 2 arguments.
See 'docker exec --help'.
```

Что я делаю не так, как сделать правильно?

Comment: Да, наверняка это не лучший способ найти id контейнера по имени образа. Если есть лучше — напишите. Но суть вопроса не про это. :)

Comment: Поменял на `docker exec -it container-name gulp`, но про Make всё ещё интересно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `Makefile`'ах `$(command arg)` имеет другую семантику нежели в командной оболочке — это [вызов внутренней функции](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Syntax-of-Functions.html#Syntax-of-Functions) `make` (или раскрытие имени переменной аналогично `${VAR}`, если нет аргументов). А чтобы выполнить внешнюю команду в свою очередь нужно воспользоваться функцией [`shell`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html#Shell-Function). Кроме того `make` будет пытаться раскрыть `$1` самостоятельно несмотря на кавычки, поэтому надо [удвоить знак доллара](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reference.html#Reference). В итоге строка должна выглядеть как-то так:

```
task:
    docker exec -it $(shell docker ps -a | grep name | awk '{print $$1}') gulp
```